# How do I compile Forth code for the J1 CPU?

Tags: compilation, fpga, forth

I am interested in using the [J1 CPU](http://excamera.com/sphinx/fpga-j1.html) in an FPGA project.

I understand that to use the J1 CPU itself, I need to synthesise (etc.) the Verilog code, and load the bitstream into my FPGA. I can do this using IceStorm, or the FPGA vendor's own tools. No problems.

I don't understand how to compile a Forth program which can be uploaded to the FPGA's memory and executed.

What command do I run to compile a Forth program into a .hex file?

Comment: According to the [J1 Forth CPU](http://excamera.com/sphinx/fpga-j1.html) web page, and the [demo program](http://excamera.com/files/j1demo.tar.gz) they provide, it looks like the tool they use is gforth to compile on the PC.

Comment: The j1demo firmware Makefile teaches a method for producing j1 executable memory images using gforth. j1.mem contains an offset and 16 bit hex values, j1.bin a binary value the size of the RAM intended for inclusion in FPGA programming image. They are products of interpretative execution of a forth and python code in the firmware directory. In lieu of loading a new FPGA image with each new 'program' you could use a firmware loader and HW I/O (top.v has a commented out UART for example, there's an Ethernet bootloader in loader.fs intended for the platform originally used,...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am aware of SwapForth, which I believe is a Forth interpreter which runs on the J1 CPU itself

You are wrong here. SwapForth is an interactive compiler, not the interpreter.

Maybe it does more than you need - handling dictionaries, accepting new code from the UART (after all, it's a complete Forth system), which you might not need at all, but that doesn't make it an interpreter.

To compile your own code, run `gforth cross.fs basewords.fs your_prog.fs`. Note that `cross.fs` is quite minimalistic, and doesn't even provide `variable`/`value` words. But you can easily add those (and many more) directly to `cross.fs`.

Answer (score 4):

Please,take a look at the [github repository with swapforth](https://github.com/jamesbowman/swapforth). It contains complete implementations for FPGA like J1A and J1B.

With J1B I have even created a complete system for initialization and diagnostics of a relatively complex FPGA-based board - [AFCK_J1B_FORTH](https://github.com/wzab/AFCK_J1B_FORTH).

To compile the code with new words, I use the [Verilator emulation](https://github.com/jamesbowman/swapforth/tree/master/j1b/verilator) of J1B. So you do not need the real J1B in hardware to prepare the code.
The whole process is also described [in the README of AFCK_J1B_FORTH](https://github.com/wzab/AFCK_J1B_FORTH#how-to-create-the-hex-file-with-new-words).

Answer (score 1):

It is an interpreter, which also compiles, try the simulated swapforth on your pc, running on python. Or you can write forth source on the pc to load/interpret/compile.